# How to add a primary key to all tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

While migrating from MS Access to SQL Server and then using Entity Framework on it, I got this issue. None of the tables have a primary key, which is required for them to be imported to an Entity Framework model.

Comment: downvoters should write their reasons for downvoting.

Comment: Whilst self-answered questions are explicitly part of the SO system, the question should *stand as a question*. You've only got two sentences in the body of your question and one of those is actually a comment that belongs on your answer. I'd suggest that that *may* be a reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I edited the question and answer both. Let me know if it still doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? ADD id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED"
```

The good thing is that it if it fails for some table, it doesn't fail for all.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DECLARE @Qry NVARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT  
    Qry = 
       'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE name =''SeqNo'' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('''+T.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+T.TABLE_NAME+'''))
       BEGIN
          ALTER TABLE '+T.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+T.TABLE_NAME+'
          ADD SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT Pk_'+T.TABLE_NAME+'_SeqNo PRIMARY KEY
       END
       GO
       '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
       LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
          ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
             AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
             AND T.TABLE_CATALOG = C.TABLE_CATALOG
             AND C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
          WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_NAME IS NULL
             AND T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
)
SELECT 
    @Qry = STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + Qry
    FROM CTE
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

EXEC @Qry
```