# How can I set all ID fields to primary key?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have 15 tables in SQL Server. Each of them has an ID (int) column. How can I set all those ID fields to PRIMARY KEY and AUTOINCREMENT in a short or single SQL query?

Comment: You can't make an existing column an `IDENTITY` column, a column can only be specified as an `IDENTITY` column at the point it is created.

Comment: Related: [SQL Server add auto increment primary key to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4862385/1220550)

Comment: Also related: [How to add a primary key to all tables in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48760581/1220550) - although this **adds** a new ID column + sets it as PK for each table. Converting is not so easy, as already mentioned above.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your reply, I can still make them PRIMARY KEY and AUTOINCREMENT 1 by using SQL server management tool, but it takes time because I have to repeat that action 15 times in 15 tables. So I'm looking if there is a SQL query that can solve.

Comment: @TrầnNgọc You can have SSMS save the change you did as SQL script instead of applying it. You can then make 15 copies of that script, find/replace the table name in each copy, and then run all of them.

Comment: @TrầnNgọc SSMS doesn't "change" the column to be an `IDENTITY`, it completely recreates the table, with all it's `CONSTRAINT`s, `INDEX`es, etc, etc, as a new name, `INSERT`s the data from the existing table into that one, `DROP`s all the `CONSTRAINT`s, `INDEX`es, etc, and then renames the new table, and them, finally, recreates any foreign key constraints on other tables. That's why it takes so long.

Comment: @PeterB I rightclick an ID column, then select Set Primary Key, then in the colum propties ---> identity specification ---> (is Identity) : change to Yes, now how can I view the SQLquery string that can update the table instead of Ctrl + S and save it?

Comment: I extended my comment above to a full Answer, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script needed to do this is actually not simple but *very complicated*. Fortunately SMSS can generate it for you (based on changes you make to 1 table). You can then make copies of  that script, adapt those copies for each table, and then run them.

**Steps:**

- Make sure that you disabled the SSMS option "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation":

  [image: SSMS Prevent saving changes]
- Then, make the needed changes in the Table Designer for 1 of your tables.
- DO NOT press the Save button in the toolbar - instead, right click in the Designer window and choose the option **Generate Change Script**:

  [image: SSMS Generate Change Script]
- Save the SQL file, it will look something like this:

  ```
  /* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  SET ARITHABORT ON
  SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
  SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  SET ANSI_PADDING ON
  SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
  COMMIT
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  GO
  CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Table1
    (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
  GO
  ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_Table1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
  GO
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table1 ON
  GO
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_Table1 (ID)
        SELECT ID FROM dbo.Table1 WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
  GO
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table1 OFF
  GO
  DROP TABLE dbo.Table1
  GO
  EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_Table1', N'Table1', 'OBJECT' 
  GO
  ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    ID
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

  GO
  COMMIT
  ```
- Make 15 copies of the script file, then in each replace `Table1` (or whatever was saved for you) with the respective 15 table names that you want to process.
- Also edit each script to INSERT...SELECT the proper columns for each table, if your tables contain data already.
- Run the 15 copies.